# Property Triggers is not working in the code-behind

Tags: triggers, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms in which i have used property triggers behind the code all coding is been done .Please help me out what mistake i did in the code.

```cs
Label header = new Label
{
   Text = "Trigger",
   Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize(50),
   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};

Entry enter = new Entry
{
    Placeholder = "Enter Name"
};

Trigger trigger = new Trigger(typeof(Entry))
{
    Property = Entry.IsFocusedProperty,
    Value = "True"
};

trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter
{
    Property = VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty,
    Value = Color.Red
});

enter.Triggers.Add(trigger);

this.Content = new StackLayout
{
    Children = 
    {
        header,
        enter
    }
};
```

Only Trigger part is not working